# R prevent repeated items while using paste() for vectors

Tags: r, paste

Consider the following:

```
a = 1:10
paste("The list is:", a)
```

And the result would be:

```
 [1] "The list is: 1"  "The list is: 2"  "The list is: 3"  "The list is: 4" 
 [5] "The list is: 5"  "The list is: 6"  "The list is: 7"  "The list is: 8" 
 [9] "The list is: 9"  "The list is: 10"
```

I have solved it by:

```
paste("The list is:", paste(a, collapse=", "))
# "The list is: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"
```

Is there any better idea?

Comment: You could `sprintf`. `sprintf('The list is: %s', paste(a, collapse=', '))`. but that isn't much help

Comment: No, this is what I'd do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess it depends what you want it for. If you are pasting this together to display in the R console, say as a note or information, then `cat()` works a bit more intuitively:

```
R> cat("The list is:", a, "\n")
The list is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

or

```
R> cat("The list is:", a, fill = TRUE)
The list is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

If you want the actual character string as an R object I don't think you'll get much simpler than the `paste()` idiom you show.

Comment: Nice idea. And if you want the character string, you could do: `capture.output(cat("The list is:", a, fill = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
paste(c("The list is:", a), collapse= " ")
```